# Not possible to print data in nested array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have these json values which i am trying to parse using React-Native.

```
{
"language": "es", 
"location": "Test", 
"clusters": [["https://elcaso.elnacional.cat/ca/successos/porsche-xoca-parquing-centre-comercial-fuenlabrada-imatges_25731_102.html", "https://motor.ara.cat/novetats/Seat-Leon-2020-leaked-filtrat_0_2388361324.html", "https://www.ara.cat/dossier/Nou-histories-ascensor-social-funciona_0_2383561636.html"], ["https://www.ccma.cat/catradio/alacarta/la-nit-dels-ignorants-3-0/per-que-predominen-les-males-noticies-als-mitjans-de-comunicacio/audio/1061759/", "https://www.ccma.cat/catradio/catalunya-musica/vols-participar-de-public-a-les-audicions-intimes/noticia/2984241/", "https://www.elnacional.cat/ca/salut/hidrats-greixos-harvard-important-qualitat_464226_102.html", "https://www.nuvol.com/art/per-que-sha-cancel-lat-la-biennal-dart-contemporani-79358"]]}
```

Then, i created below code to loop over the nested array and print the url values:

```
  render() {
    if (this.state.isLoading) {
      return (
        <View style={{flex: 1, padding: 20}}>
          <ActivityIndicator />
        </View>
      );
    }

    return (
      <ScrollView style={{flex: 1, paddingTop: 20}}>
        <Text>{this.state.dataSource.language}</Text>
        <Text>{this.state.dataSource.location}</Text>
        <Text>{this.state.dataSource.type}</Text>

        {this.state.dataSource.clusters.map(clusters => {
          //console.log(clusters);
          {
            typeof clusters === 'object';
            clusters.map(datas => {
              console.log(datas);
              return (
                <Text>{datas}</Text>
              );
            });
          }
          return (
            //<view key={clusters}>
            //<Text>{clusters}</Text>
            <Text>SEPARATOR</Text>
            //</view>
          );
        })}
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
```

And strangely, the console.log(datas); is correctly printing the data, but the return of the {datas} is not returning any data.

I have been looking for it for days and i don't find the reason. Does anyone of you know what i am missing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I read, you're telling React to :

1. Map on your `dataSource.clusters`
2. Making a comparison with `typeof clusters === 'object';` which is equal to a boolean `true/false`, but neither returned of affected to a value, so it might have no effect
3. Map on `dataSource.clusters[index].clusters`, each of them containing `datas`
4. Then returning `<Text>{datas}</Text>` but in a nested `.map()` so it wont be rendered, it will just return `<Text>{datas}</Text>` in your first `.map()` callback function. You're not affecting those returns to any variable.

In my opinion, this should be extracted in a method that takes your json datas in input, and returns an array :

```js
extractDataFromClusters(dataSource) => {
   let datas = []
   dataSource.clusters.map( cluster => { 
      cluster.map( data => datas.push(`<Text>${data}</Text>`) )
      datas.push(`<Text>SEPARATOR</Text>`)
   })
   return datas
}
```

Then in your `render()` function, you could map on your data in a single loop :

```js
   {this.extractDataFromClusters(this.state.dataSource).map( data => data )}
```